# Twitter api authentication flex mobile flash builder

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, twitter, flash-builder

i'm making a mobile app in flash builder 4.6.
The should show some tweets with specific hashtags. 
after a very long search i've finally found a document that helped me.
I'm using this guide http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/flex/articles/twitter-trends/build-first-mobile-flex-app.pdf
But it uses the older version of the twitter API. 
Now it needs authorization. 
And I'm totaly new to flash builder so I don't get where I have to do this (in which file) or what I should type there...

Comment: Show us the source code you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've solved it ,

this is an example of how our source code looks like in which we authorize the api and get/show the tweets.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="TOUS ENSEMBLE"
    initialize="init()">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <s:ArrayCollection id="tweets" />
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />
        <s:State name="busy"/>
        <s:State name="networkError"/>
    </s:states>


    <s:List id="list" top="0" left="0" right="0" bottom="0" dataProvider=" {tweets}">
        <s:itemRenderer>
            <fx:Component>
                <s:ItemRenderer>
                    <s:Image source="{data.user.profile_image_url}" left="0" verticalCenter="0" width="60" height="60"/>
                    <s:Label text="{data.text}" left="65" right="5" top="5" bottom="5"/>
                </s:ItemRenderer>
            </fx:Component>
        </s:itemRenderer>

    </s:List>
    <s:BusyIndicator id="busy" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0" width="60" height="60" includeIn="busy"/>
    <s:Label id="networkError" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0" text="Network Error Occured" includeIn="networkError"/>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import de.danielyan.twitterAppOnly.TwitterSocket;
            import de.danielyan.twitterAppOnly.TwitterSocketEvent;

            private var _twitter:TwitterSocket;
            private var searchTweetKeyword;

            public function init():void
            {
                _twitter = new TwitterSocket('I9ItnPjy670SsLOBcas5pJHGY', 'GpuPGqrCfRm53LpayKOVtGjdOFZNY3mTycQHJc2vf3SAeXDqME');

                // twitter socket uses two events: 
                _twitter.addEventListener(TwitterSocket.EVENT_TWITTER_READY, onTwitterReady);
                // * The Twitter Data event, when the twitter Request has finished
                _twitter.addEventListener(TwitterSocket.EVENT_TWITTER_RESPONSE, onTwitterData);
                // * Catch IO Errors! This happens when no network is available
                _twitter.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,onError);
                currentState="busy";
            }
            public function onError(event:Event):void
            {
                currentState="networkError";
            }

            public function onTwitterReady(event:Event):void
            {
                _twitter.request("/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=#belgianreddevils");
            }

            public function onTwitterData(event:TwitterSocketEvent):void
            {
                    // this message is 
                 currentState="normal";
                var tweetList =  new ArrayCollection(event.response.statuses as Array);
                //tweets = new ArrayCollection(event.response.statuses as Array);
                trace(tweetList[0].text);
                tweets = tweetList;


            }



        ]]>
     </fx:Script>
</s:View>
```

we've used help from the pdf that I've included and this github documentation 
https://github.com/denisdanielyan/as3-Application-Only-Twitter